# CruiseControl.Net continues to build even if there's no new source

Tags: .net, configuration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm having a problem with configuring CC.Net. My current setup for the project looks like this (sanitised to get rid of confidential stuff):

```
<project name="WebApp">
    <workingDirectory>c:\cc\WebApp\Code</workingDirectory>
    <artifactDirectory>c:\cc\WebApp\Artifacts</artifactDirectory>   
    <webURL>http://example.com/ccnet</webURL>
    <modificationDelaySeconds>10</modificationDelaySeconds> 
    <triggers>
      <intervalTrigger seconds="30" name="continuous" />
    </triggers>


<sourcecontrol type="multi">
<sourceControls autogetsource="true">
<svn>
    <trunkUrl>svn+ssh://build@192.168.2.12/webapp/trunk</trunkUrl>
    <executable>C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe</executable>
    <username>build</username>
    <password>********</password>
    <revisionNumbers>true</revisionNumbers>
</svn>
<svn>
    <trunkUrl>svn+ssh://build@192.168.2.12/dataservice/trunk</trunkUrl>
    <executable>C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe</executable>
    <username>build</username>
    <password>********</password>
    <revisionNumbers>true</revisionNumbers>
    <workingDirectory>..\dataservice</workingDirectory>
</svn>  
<svn>
    <trunkUrl>svn+ssh://build@192.168.2.12/WCFProxyClasses/WCFProxyClasses/trunk</trunkUrl>
    <executable>C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe</executable>
    <username>build</username>
    <password>********</password>
    <revisionNumbers>true</revisionNumbers>
    <workingDirectory>..\proxies\WCFProxyClasses</workingDirectory>
</svn>  
</sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>

    <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
            <projectFile>WebApp/WebApp.msbuild</projectFile>
            <targets>BeforeBuild;Build;AfterBuild</targets>
            <timeout>300</timeout>
            <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
    </tasks>

    <publishers>
        <rss/>
        <xmllogger />
        <statistics />
        <!-- Email build report to development and QA team -->
        <email from="ccnet_noreply@example.com" mailhost="mailhost" mailport="25" includeDetails="TRUE" mailhostUsername="" mailhostPassword="" useSSL="FALSE">
        <users>                 
            <user name="Developer" group="devs" address="dev@example.com"/>
        </users>
        <groups>
            <group name="devs"/>
        </groups>
        <converters/>
        <modifierNotificationTypes>
            <NotificationType>Always</NotificationType>
        </modifierNotificationTypes>
        </email>
        <modificationHistory  onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
    </publishers>
</project>
```

We have multiple source control targets because the web app project is dependant on the others. I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue (which I'm getting to) or not. I'm have little experience (none!) with CC.Net so I don't really know where to look. The we have other projects in the config file, but none of them have multiple source control targets and they are all behaving as expected.

The problem with this project is that regardless of source control changes, it simple attempts to build every 30 seconds! As far as I understand, the `<revisionNumbers>` tag is supposed to make CC.Net wait for a new source revision before building again, however it just keeps building and sending out emails, every 30 seconds.

If you need more information I will give it. I'm hoping somebody recognises what's going wrong here or has experienced the problem before and might have some suggestions for me.

Thanks!

EDIT -

If it helps, the project defined above fails to build every time. This is due to certain 3rd party DLLs referenced in the project not being available on the CC.Net server. Could the failed build be causing it to "try again" every 30 seconds?

Comment: I don't see `autogetsource="true"` on `<sourceControls>` in the documentation, are you sure it is correct?

The `<intervalTrigger/>` should by default only build on `<buildCondition>IfModificationExists</buildCondition>`, so your source controls must be reporting changes on each check.

Why do you use multiple source control blocks here instead of svn externals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

- Explicitly mention `buildCondition="IfModificationExists"` (though it should be the [default](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Interval+Trigger))...
- Leave only one source control at a time to find the culprit that keeps triggering the build.
- Check log (the svn outputs) to see what is being updated (like Pedro offered).

HTH

Comment: Tried a single source control at a time and all three worked on their own. It seems to be a problem with multi source control. I have reworked the config file with project triggers instead. All seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

On the build summary for the project, what does it list as having been modified? For svn, you should see a section that says "Modifications since last build" followed by a list of files, checkin time, and checkin comments.

Is there anything in the build that is checking files back into svn (AssemblyInfo.cs maybe?)

Edit:

You mention in your update that it is failing to build each time. Until this is fixed, I suspect you are going to get such retries.  Why it keeps retrying, however, I'm not entirely sure.  One difference between your scripts and the ones we use, is we do not use the "revisionNumbers" tag for svn items (though I'm not sure that is the issue.)

You also mention that it found 534 modifications since last build.  Is that number increasing for each new build?  If the number is increasing, you may have something else checking a file or files into the repository, which would cause another build to kick off.

Comment: The latest build log says "Integration Request:  Build (IfModificationExists) triggered from continuous". "Modifications since last build (534) "